# How to correctly mock node-fetch?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm having problems mocking `node-fetch` it is not mocking and makes an actual request to an API.

Here is the module I'm trying to mock

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export const createUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://website.com/users', { method: 'GET' });
    const userId = await response.json();
    return userId;
};
```

Test

```
import { createUser } from '../createUser';
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

const mockFetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
    Promise.resolve({
        json: async () => ({
            id: 4
        })
    })
);

it("tests get request" , async () => {
    const userId = await createUser(); // makes an actual request
    expect(userId.id).toBe(4);
    expect(mockFetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://website.com/users', {
        method: 'GET'
    });
})
```

Another way I tried to mock like it is specified in docs, but getting an error that  `fetch.mockResolvedValueOnce` is not a function

```
jest.mock('node-fetch');

import { createUser } from '../createUser';
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

it("tests get request", async () => {
    fetch.mockResolvedValueOnce(
        Promise.resolve(() => ({
            id: 4
        }))
    );
    const userId = await createUser(); // makes an actual request
    expect(userId.id).toBe(4);
})
```